# Expected value and standard error question.

Tags: probability, statistics, average

Suppose there are two boxes, $A$ and $B$. Box $A$ contains three tickets: $1$, $3$, and $5$. Box $B$ has two tickets: $2$ and $4$. One number is drawn from box $A$ and one number is drawn from box $B$. Let $X$ be the number from $A$, and $Y$ be the number from $B$.

What is expected value and standard error of $X+Y$.

Here is my thought:
the box of possibility is $\{3,5,5,7,7,9\}$

For expected value, we have (average of box)$\times$(number of draws)$=6\times 1=6$. For standard error, we have SE=$\sqrt{number \ of\  draws}\times$ SD=$1\times\sqrt{\frac{22}{6}}$

But I think this method is pretty slow and I am not sure the validity of the result. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Is there... an end to that sentence??

Comment: Expected value is indeed 6

Comment: @CoolKid Paging... Uh, what is the end of your last sentence???

Answer (score 2):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent. Therefore $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$

And $Var(X)=\sum_{i=1}^3 p_i (x_i-\mu_x)^2 =\frac13 (1-2)^2+\frac13 (2-2)^2+\frac13 (3-2)^2$

Similar for $Var(Y)$

The standard errors are

$\sigma_{\overline X}=\frac{\sigma_X}{\sqrt n_x}=\sigma_X$

$\sigma_{\overline Y}=\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sqrt n_y}=\sigma_Y$

$n_x$ and $n_y$ are the number of draws. In both cases it is 1.

$Var(X)=\sigma_X^2, \ Var(Y)=\sigma_Y^2$

Thus the standard error of $X+Y$ is $\sigma_{\overline X +\overline Y}=\sqrt{Var(X)+Var(Y)}$

Comment: which would be $\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}+\frac{2}{2}}$ which is indeed the same as    $\sqrt{\frac{22}{6}}$ when both are simplified

Comment: @Henry Yes. But the way how the OP has calculated is not clear. For instance, $SE=\sqrt{\text{number of draws}}\cdot SD$ looks not right to me. It is the other way round.

Comment: Indeed.  "Standard error" is slightly odd too, given a single draw: "standard deviation" might be clearer in that case

Comment: @Henry I agree to you.